# Add hyperlink to references in RMarkdown

Tags: hyperlink, reference, r-markdown

In the YAML of an RMarkdown document I have

```
link-citations: yes
bibliography: citations.bib
csl: biomed-central.csl
```

which adds a list of  the references used at the end of the document. One is also directed to different levels of that list when clicking on the different citations added throughout the text. I would like to go a step further and add hyperlinks to the references showing on that list, so that it is possible to go to the website where the original reference lies right from the rendered RMarkdown document in just one click. Is this possible?

Comment: To clarify: you want a citation like `@doe2022` to become a link with text "Doe (2022)" that points to the external resource `https://doi.org/THEDOI` instead of to the entry in the bibliography? Maybe you could add a little example to the question to make this clearer?

Comment: @tarleb Not exactly. `@doe2022` would direct to the entry in the bibliography since `link-citations: yes`. I would like the entries created in the bibliography to contain hyperlinks to be able to go the external resource where each entry is hosted. It looks though that the citations in bib format that I generate from the corresponding DOIs do not usually include url, so looks like I would need to modify myself each bib citation to include their urls and find a citation style that shows it.

Comment:  That's the issue then, updating the citation database should do it.

Comment: Even if I do as mentioned above, I do not think those urls showing in the entries would be hyperlinks themselves, so not sure it is worth to do it since the title of the entries can be copied and googled.

Comment: Take a look at <https://joss.theoj.org>. The papers there are compiled with pandoc (same engine as used by R Markdown) and the APA citation style. Check if that's what you want.

Comment: Looks almost like what i want, would like the citations within the text to be numbered. Do you know where i can find the .csl file for such citation style or alternatively the .csl for joss ? Thanks!